# Codeigniter parameter changes during pagination

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I am using regular CodeIgniter Pagination Class. Whenever I change the page number the parameter that has been sent gets replaced with the pagination parameters.

I am using HMVC file structure. I'm trying to set something like:

`folder/class/function/some_parameter/pagination_parameter`

But for some reason i'm unable to use `$config['uri_segment'] = '5';`

Comment: Make sure the `$config['uri_segment'] = 3;` is set to right value. In your case you might need 4, or something else if you're using routers for that page.

Comment: Post your controller.

Comment: I am using HMVC file structure. I'm trying to set something like..... folder/class/function/some_parameter/pagination_parameter

but for some reason i'm unable to use $config['uri_segment'] = '5'